# Trying to pass parameters as functions in Python

Tags: python, function, sorting, parameters

I have this:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, FirstName, LastName):
        self.FirstName = FirstName
        self.LastName = LastName

    def __iter__(self):                                            
        return self

Students = [
#       FirstName   LastName   
Student("Mary",     "Smith"),
Student("Joe",      "Jones"),    
Student("Jane",     "Doe"  )]
```

I make a `Student` class. And then I make a list of 3 `Student` objects.
Then I can print a list of the names like this:

```
for item in Students:
    print item.FirstName, item.LastName
```

And it obediently outputs this:

```
Mary Smith
Joe Jones
Jane Doe
```

Then I googled how to sort a list of objects by an attribute and found this:

```
Students.sort(key = lambda x: x.LastName)
```

And it works. That line sort the list by the `LastName` attribute and I can print it the same way as above and the names are in order by `LastName`:

```
Jane Doe
Joe Jones
Mary Smith
```

But what I want to happen is have user inputs for what list to sort (`sortlist`) and by which attribute to sort by (`sortby`). So I tried:

```
def sort(sortlist, sortby):
    sortlist.sort(key = lambda x: x.sortby)

sort(Students, FirstName)
```

And that doesn't work. First it says:

```
NameError: "name 'FirstName' is not defined"
```

Which is it's own problem… How do I tell it that `FirstName` is an attribute of the list I want it to sort?

Then I made `FirstName` a string just to try that…

```
AttributeError: "Student instance has no attribute 'sortby'"
```

Which I know there's no attribute `sortby`, that's supposed to be a parameter… but it can't use a parameter like that? Why not? How can I make it do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is actually looking for an attribute called 'sortby' which of course would not exist.  Use the getattr builtin to fetch the attribute from the object using a string instead of the identifier.

```
def sort(sortlist, sortby):
    sortlist.sort(key = lambda x: getattr(x, sortby))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `attrgetter` from the `operator` module:

```
from operator import attrgetter
def sort(sortlist, sortby):
    sortlist.sort(key=attrgetter(sortby))
```